# 2D character array contents getting overwritten

Tags: c

I am trying to read a string and reverse the words in the string., but the content of the strings is getting overwritten and I am getting garbage values for the first few strings in the 2D array. E.g. when I print the words in reverse order at the end of the function, I am getting junk for the first few strings. What am I doing wrong?

```
void reverseWords(char *s) {
    char** words;
    int word_count = 0;

    /*Create an array of all the words that appear in the string*/
    const char *delim = " ";
    char *token;
    token = strtok(s, delim);
    while(token != NULL){
        word_count++;
        words = realloc(words, word_count * sizeof(char));
        if(words == NULL){
            printf("malloc failed\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        words[word_count - 1] = strdup(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    /*Traverse the list backwards and check the words*/
    int count = word_count;
    while(count > 0){
        printf("%d %s\n",count - 1, words[count - 1]);
        count--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: you should initialize your "words" variable to NULL.

Comment: There is no 2D `char` array! Please rephrase your title.

Comment: Also, if `realloc` returns `NULL`, the original array is still allocated and you are leaking memory.

Comment: Since this is a runtime problem, please post code that 1) cleanly compiles, 2) is small 3) shows the problem.    I.E. the #include statements and a main() function that calls the posted function need to be added.

Comment: for robustness, the code should check that s != NULL and that *s != '\0' before beginning the parsing.  Otherwise, the posted code will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change that line:

```
words = realloc(words, word_count * sizeof(char));
```

You allocate `char`s, that is, single characters. You want pointers. Therefore, use this:

```
words = realloc(words, word_count * sizeof(char*));
```

Also, as @[Snild Dolkow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4811803/snild-dolkow) stated, initialize `words` to `NULL`. Otherwise `realloc` will attempt to use the undefined value of `words` as the memory to reallocate. Further information at `man realloc`.

---

Notes:

- You should `free` the memory returned to you by `strdup` after usage

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I thought I was using sizeof(char*). Works now! Cheers!

Comment: Nah. The canonical way is **not to use `sizeof(type)`** but `sizeof *ptr_to_realloc` as in `words = realloc(words, word_count * sizeof *words))`.

Comment: @LeelakrishnaN If this solved your problem you should press the check mark under the voting arrows to accept it as the correct answer

Comment: never use the returned value from realloc() with out first checking that the value is not NULL.  Otherwise the original pointer to some allocated memory would be overwritten with NULL, resulting in a memory leak